# Android - share UI between applications

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an application "app_a" which contains a fragment ("fragment_a") with a RecyclerView to show content. The content is from database of "app_a". There may be some buttons on each RecyclerView item, click these buttons will modify some database value of "app_a".
I would like to show same content on another application "app_b" without duplicated code. Tap buttons on RecyclerView item in "app_b" will also modify database value of "app_a". Can anyone give me some suggestions to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: So... to make it clear, you will have two apps that modify the same data (so, the model will be the same) and you also want to share the UI (so, the view is also the same). Might I suggest you to take a look at [build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html), if the modification is small enough?

Comment: Move the fragment_a to an android library and let both app_a and app_b use that library, this way you'll share(more precisely, you'll have the option to use the same UI without duplicating the code) the UI code between the apps. To also share the data you'll need to implement a ContentProvider in app_a to expose its data(in the previous android library you'll need to include the contract class of that ContentProvider so both apps will know how to talk to the ContentProvider in app_a).

Comment: @Korcholis Thanks for your reply. However, the build variants seems to used to build a single application by different modes. Could you elaborate how it can be used in this case?

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks for your reply. Yes, move the fragment to a shared library is one solution. We might need to consider version control because app_a and app_b may use different library versions. I wonder if there are other solutions which can avoid version control.

Comment: [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) seems to be one candidate, but it seems to only support limited layout and control, and it uses broadcasts for communication which may not has good performance. [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) might be another candidate, but when I load fragment_a into app_b, it causes Resources$NotFoundException in fragment_a. I haven't found the solution for this.

Comment: @TimWang with one single codebase you can apply modifications to the apps you compile (even a package name and title change). In the end, you could compile 2 (or tens of) apps that differ in texts, imagery, package names and so, from one single shared codebase. Almost everything could be modified "automatically", and any other change (code-related) should also be manually done by doing some checks (this is an assumption). _Personal comment: sadly my company developed an internal way to generate different apps from the same codebase before build variants, but this is a pretty solid solution_